# Touchstart, touchend javascript counter

Tags: javascript, android, ios, touchscreen

Is there possible way to track how long user is holding finger, and every 1 second change something in html.

I found this example http://jsfiddle.net/7Z6hg/ in one post, but it's with keydown.

```
$(function () {
    var keyTimes = {};

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (keyTimes["key" + e.which]) {
            return false;
        }
        keyTimes["key" + e.which] = new Date().getTime();
    });

    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (keyTimes["key" + e.which]) {
            var x = new Date().getTime() - keyTimes["key" + e.which];
            delete keyTimes["key" + e.which];
            $("<p />").text("Held key " + e.which + " for " + x / 1000.0 + " seconds").appendTo("div");
        }
    });
});
```

Are there any events for touch devices?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

- Use `Date-object` to get the `Date` on which event is initiated
- Use `+(Unary plus)` to get time-stamp of the `Date-object`
- Dividing the difference by `1000` will return `seconds`

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
var date;
elem.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
  date = +new Date();
});
elem.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
  var diff = +new Date() - date;
  console.log((diff / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' seconds');
});
```

```css
#elem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem">Element</div>
```